# Does a network force the JVM to use a smaller stack/heap limit?

Tags: networking, error-handling, out-of-memory

I am trying to develop a game in my Java class, but after a few minutes of playing it at school, I get a OutOfMemory error. However, if I run it at my house, I can seemingly play it indefinitely without the error showing. The CPU/RAM monitor that is on Windows 7 and Vista is near maxed out at school while running the program (it hits %100 CPU, and %90+ RAM), however at home, I can't see a difference in the CPU meter, and the RAM meter only goes up a few percent.

So, is it the fault of the school network, or is it a matter of the massive difference in specs between the schools computers, and my own?

Comment: Well, what *are* those differences?

Comment: Are you using the same version of java with same memory arguments at both locations (using -Xms and -Xmx args)?

Comment: @Chris: No, I allocated more at the school as one of my attempts to alleviate the problem (currently it's set at 1024 mb for both Xmx, and Xms. I don't have any arguments at my home computer).

Comment: @Delnan: I'm not aware of the schools processor, but it's at least 4 years old (and obviously cheap, since they are mass-ordered for a high school), and they have 2GB of DDR2 RAM. My computer has an i7-2600K with 4GB of DDR3 RAM.